# What is the difference between "the nature of software" and "nature of software"?

Tags: difference, definite-article

> 1. **The** Nature of Software
> 2. Nature of Software

This would be the title of a blog and I do not know what are the slight differences between the two.

Comment: With no determiner or qualification, *Nature* means the natural world, the physical universe. ***The** nature of* something means its fundamental or essential quality.

Comment: The same would be true for words like _essence_ and _character_. You would probably want to include _the_ in the title of a blog using those words, too, such as _The Essence of Engineering_ or _The Character of the Programmer_.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer! @StoneyB What does "the natural world, the physical universe" mean in case of software? Could you please tell me an example? Or in case of software, without the determiner/qualification it does not mean anything?

Comment: That's just the point: "Nature of Software" is on its face meaningless--though I suppose a Philosopher of Software could make it mean something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what StoneyB says, with no determiner/qualification, it would mean the natural world and with **the**, it refers to the fundamental quality.

I'll add a little bit to this - when it comes to **the title**, the authors are *quite flexible* in grammar rules. I have read several titles without definite/indefinite articles though they all required.

I'm not sure but see the titles [here](http://www.evolution.berkeley.edu/evosite/nature/index.shtml), [here](http://soundcloud.com/natureofmusic) and [here](http://www.naturenw.org/).

Comment: That flexibility stems in part from the fact that a title is a title, not a complete sentence. Not all grammatical rules apply.